# Roscpp warning in ros::Publisher::publish

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am worried about the following warning that is given when compiling roscpp programs which contains a publisher:

```
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h: In member function ‘void ros::Publisher::publish(const M&) const [with M = geometry_msgs::PoseStamped]’:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/publisher.h:112: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour
```

The publisher:

```
ros::Publisher goalPub = this->n.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>("move_base_simple/goal", 1);
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped msg;
msg.header.frame_id = "/map";
msg.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
msg.pose.position.x=mygoal.x;
msg.pose.position.y=mygoal.y;
msg.pose.orientation=tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(angle);
goalPub.publish(msg);
```

But the warning is given for all the publishers:

```
ros::Publisher cmdPub = this->n.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("cmd_vel", 1);
cmdPub.publish(msg);
```

My machine is ubuntu 12.10 with the latest version of ros-groovy and gcc 4.4.7.

Is this warning dangeours? is it being adresses? is it considered a 'bug'? if so, where can I open a ticket for it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/53930/roscpp-warning-in-ros::publisher::publish/) by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on ROS Answers with karma: 483 on 2013-02-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-01**:
Would you please add the code invoking `publish()`, by editing your question?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-02-01**:
It might be that the compile gets more verbose about warnings with later versions, but are you sure you are using 4.4.7? On Oneiric I already have 4.6.1.

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-02-01**:
Yes, I had to downgrade to able to compile something... (CUDA maybe?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you hit a bug in roscpp introduced 10 days ago. The `const char *` result of `mt::md5sum<M>(message)` is compared with the string literal `"*"` in [publisher.h:112](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/aa3adf0020e451005e5fea9ba9d9085fe87c676c/clients/roscpp/include/ros/publisher.h#L112). The warning also appears in newer versions of gcc (like 4.6.3 in a standard Ubuntu precise installation).

Created a ticket: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/165.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Victor_ocv2](https://answers.ros.org/users/3431/victor_ocv2/) on 2013-02-02**:
Thank you!